# deferred Rxjs BehaviorSubject mechanism

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have the following requirement.

I have An Angular service with an BehaviorSubject.
A http request is done and when this is done the BehaviorSubject.next method is invoked with the value.
This value can change during the lifecycle of the single page.

Different subscribers are registered to it and get invoked whenever this changes.

The problem is that while the http request is pending the BehaviorSubject already contains a default value and subscribers are already immediately getting this value.

What I would want is that subscribers have to wait till the http request is done (deferred) and get the value when the http request is done and sets the value.
So what I need is some kind of deferred Behavior subject mechanism.

How would i implement this using rxjs?

Another requirement is that if I subscribe to the behaviorsubject in a method we want the subcriber to get the first non default value and that the subscription ends. We don't want local subscriptions in functions to be re-executed.

Comment: Why don't you directly expose the Observable returned by the http call and need to go through a BehaviorSubject?

Comment: It sounds like you can just switch to `ReplaySubject(1)` and that's it.

Comment: Actually the http call doesn't create the value in the BehaviorSubject. It performs a backend call for authentication creates a cookie (legacy code) and when http call is done we compose an object based on the information within the cookie. Also due to some other non http actions within the application the values of this object can change (without http requests anymore).

Comment: Subscribers are unaware whether the value changes due to a http request or non-http actions. They just need to get the latest value.

Comment: I'm playing around with the ReplaySubject. What I also want is that if in a method a subscription is done to the subject: We wait till the first value is emitted and than we unsubcribe to prevent the subscription in the method to be called over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a filter on your behavior subject so your subscribers won't get the first default emitted value:

```
mySubject$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

httpResponse$: Observable<any> = this.mySubject$.pipe(
  filter(response => response)
  map(response => {
     const modifyResponse = response;
    // modify response
    return modifyResponse;
  }),
  take(1)
);
this.httpResponse$.subscribe(response => console.log(response));

this.myHttpCall().subscribe(response => this.mySubject$.next(response));
```

You can of course wrap the httpResponse$ observable in a method if you need to.

Comment: I get what you mean. But what we also want is that when we get the first emitted value (non null) we want to close the subscription to prevent the closure in the function to be called over and over again.

Comment: Thus, in your component, juste before subscribing to the data, you do a `this.httpRequestObservable$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe();` so you will get only one http call. Is that what you try to achieve ?

Comment: The program works like this:
1a) http call is done to authentication 
1b) In parallel a method is invoked subscribing to the subject -> this method has to wait till http request is done to get value
2) when http call is done the value is filled in the subject
3) later on in the code some js logic is called changing the value in the subject -> the subscription in the method 1b should not be invoked anymore

Comment: I assume your httpCall is a promise ? 
In the then method, you could push the data in your subject and perform a map to change the value. I will edit my answer.

Comment: The http call is also an observable so with subscribe instead of then. I don't nee to map because the subject always contains the object in the given format??

Comment: I put a map operator because you said you wanted to put js logic to change the value coming from your http request.

Comment: Yea but that location is the result of the BehaviorSubject and not the http call isn't it? So I need to do mapping when calling this.myHttpCall()

Comment: What's going through your subject is your http response, so you are actually doing modification on the data receive by your http call with this map. But adding the map operator after your http call method is also perfectly fine, like so: 
`this.myHttpCall().pipe(map(response => { // do computation on response })).subscribe(response => this.mySubject$.next(response));`

Answer (score 0):

I think the fact that you want to defer the emitted default value, straight away brings into question why you want to use a BehaviorSubject. Let's remember: the primary reason to use a BehaviorSubject (instead of a Subject, or a plain Observable), is to emit a value **immediately** to any subscriber.

If you need an Observable type where you need control of the producer (via .next([value])) and/or you want multicasting of subscription out of the box, then *Subject* is appropriate.

**If** an additional requirement on top of this is that subscribers need a value immediately then you need to consider *BehaviorSubject*.

If you didn't say you need to update the value from other non-http events/sources, then I would've suggested using a shareReplay(1) pattern. Nevertheless...

```
private cookieData$: Subject<RelevantDataType> = new 
Subject<RelevantDataType>(null);


// Function for triggering http request to update
// internal Subject.
// Consumers of the Subject can potentially invoke this 
// themselves if they receive 'null' or no value on subscribe to subject
public loadCookieData(): Observable<RelevantDataType> {
    this.http.get('http://someurl.com/api/endpoint')
        .map(mapDataToRelevantDataType());
}

// Function for dealing with updating the service's 
// internal cookieData$ Subject from external 
// consumer which need to update this value
// via non-http events
public setCookieData(data: any): void {
    const newCookieValue = this.mapToRelevantDataType(data); // <-- If necessary
    this.cookieData$.next(newCookieValue); // <-- updates val for all subscribers
}

get cookieData(): Observable<RelevantDataType> {
    return this.cookieData$.asObservable();
}
```

The solution is based on OPs comments etc.
- deals with subscribing to subject type.
- deals with external subscribers not being able to 'next' a new value directly
- deals with external producers being able to set a new value on the Subject type
- deals with not giving a default value whilst http request is pending